# curl authentication failed in rest api

Tags: linux, rest

I'm currently  trying to authenticate REST api using  curl request.
 but it gives error http 400 bad request for my curl request.

This is the curl request i'm used

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @auth.txt https://example.com/vedsdk/Authorize/
```

auth.txt file contain credential for rest api.

***auth.txt file contain***

```
{
    "Username":"Api_Acconut",
    "Password":"8+\Kt\P;Z"
}
```

This **Api_Account** is a local account for REST Api platform.

Can anyone tell me where I'm  wrong in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the  solution. add another back slash (\) in password

{ "Username":"Api_Acconut", "Password":"**8+\\Kt\\P;Z**" }